# How to scroll to a specific location in iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page A.html, embedded page B.html through the iframe.

A.html

```
<Html>
  <Head>
   <Title> A.html </title>
  </Head>
  <Body>
   <Iframe name = "myframe" id = "myframe" src = "B.html" frameborder = "0"/> 
 </Body>
</Html>
```

B.html

```
<Html>
 <Head>
  <Title> B.html </title>
   <Style type = "text/css" media = "screen">
    .body {margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: medium;}
  </Style>
 </Head>
  <Body class = "body">
    <Table  width = "100%" height = "100%" align = "left" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0">
      .
      .
   </Table>
   <Table  width = "100%" height = "100%" align = "left" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0">
      The content I want to display!
   </Table>
   <Table  width = "100%" height = "100%" align = "left" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0">
     .
     .
   </Table>
   </Body>
   </Html>
```

I want to display B.html's table2 content in A.html, I found some methods, such as

```
 var myIframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
  myIframe.onload = function(){
      myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(100,500);
  };
```

but B.html page size is not set, and there are **three tables** with **height = "100%"**, B.html is displayed as a percentage of the page and it scrolls to three pages in the browser.
 so **scrollTo(x,y)** method does not work, Is there a good way? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: A.html is my page,B.html is not my page,it's in another server

Comment: Set the url of the iframe  `src` to `B.html/#table2` pretty sure that could scroll it to the element ID of table 2 or set whatever #ElementId you wish to scroll to?

Comment: Thank you,But there is no table id in real B.html, and B.html is not my page, I can't change it.  Are there are other ways?

Comment: In the **B.html** you have showing here clearly has an id for the tables... -- <Table **id = "table2"** width = "100%"  so why does your example source have an ID if the actual page you want to use doesn't... Can you give a better example of the page you will be working with and maybe you will get a suitable answer.

Comment: Forgive me, I worried that we could not distinguish which one table, so I added the table id.I have put it back to original and B.html is like this, except the data contents of the each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to the position of any HTML element that has an id set on it.

So, if there's a table `<table id="my-table">`, you can use an anchor link to go to it.
`<a href="#my-table">go to table</a>`

The same goes for content inside an iframe.
Set your source to the url you want, and add `#my-table` (or something similar) at the end.

In the snippet below, I've used an iframe that points directly to the `#footer` of the Stackoverflow.com homepage.

```css
.myframe {
  height: 320px;
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="myframe" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com#footer"></iframe>
```

Comment: But using an anchor would mean that you have to add the anchor into the `B.html`  where as if you just set/change the src of the iframe then you don't need to add more content into the iframed page. You are basically offering a solution that isn't what the OP is asking for and then repeating my comment above.

Comment: Thank you,But there is no table id in real B.html, and B.html is not my page, I can't change it.  Are there are other ways?